# Create temporary file and edit contents and return the path to the file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, pipe, fish

I wish to create a temporary file using `mktemp` and then edit it's content after creation (using your preferred editor; I used `micro`) and then when finished i.e. saved/exited the process it should output path to the file to stdout/pipe/replace in place as argument.

I can do all but print the path of the file created and used. I would not like to rely on editors ability to output path when closing so any editor can be used.

What I was trying.

```
# creates a file. passes it's path to editor to open it. 
# then we can make changes and save. finally quit.
> micro (mktemp)
```

But output is nothing, I want it to be the original path passed in.
How can I do that?

These are example use cases, they don't work as I cannot output the path after saving.

```
# e.g. a full test case; create tmp file, fill it, read it, find it...
> micro (mktemp) | cat | grep 'find me*!'

# or you want to count the words
> micro (mktemp) | tail | wc 

# another way it should work as well! i.e. pros-sub
> cat (micro (mktemp)) | sed 's/red/green/g'

# bonus points (I mean it, 50 extra karma). You might need to restructure the chain
# i.e. ->create tmp, fill it, save it, read it, manipulate it, save it 
# back to disk (append/replace)
> cat (micro (mktemp)) | sed ' s/red/green/g' >> <original_file_path>
```

---

I'm working in `fish` because I'm rosy eyed and am looking for solution in that. However if you know it in `bash` already, would love to see it and can be useful. So I'll tag both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the fish shell, you could define a function, here `mt`:

```
function mt
  set -l path (mktemp)
  micro $path </dev/tty >/dev/tty
  cat $path
 end
```

Now your pipelines can work with `mt`:

```
mt | wc
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `bash` solution.

Put the pathname in a variable so you can reuse it later in the script.

To get the output of a command, you use `$(command)`, not just `(command)`

```
temp=$(mktemp)
micro "$temp"
wc < "$temp"
```

Comment: he said he would accept `bash` code, I clarified that this is such. I don't know fish.